# finding log4j appender to apply to my log

Tags: java, log4j

I have my appender configured in the log4j2.xml file

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" />
    </Console>
    <Routing name="ConferenceLog">
        <Routes pattern="${ctx:logFileName}">
            <Route>
                <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:logFileName}"
                    fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${ctx:logFileName}.log" 
                    filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/${ctx:logFileName}.%i.log.gz">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" />
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20971520" />
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>
            <Route ref="Console" key="${ctx:logFileName}" />
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="conference.logger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConferenceLog" />
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

At run time Im trying to find and apply this to a particular log entry

```
private void logger(Long meetingId, Log log, Logger logger, Level level, String message, Throwable error) {
    ThreadContext.put(LOG_FILE_NAME, String.valueOf(meetingId));

    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    Appender conferenceLoggerAppender = rootLogger.getAppender("ConferenceLog");
    logger.addAppender(conferenceLoggerAppender);
    logger(log, level, message, error);
    logger.removeAppender(conferenceLoggerAppender);

    ThreadContext.remove(LOG_FILE_NAME);
}
```

but my `conferenceLoggerAppender` is always null.  What is wrong with my logic?  Im trying to change it from what we currently do which is to use conference.logger

```
Log conferenceLogger = LogFactory.getLog("conference.logger");
```

However that creates entries like so

> 2017-03-30 18:30:11.576 [taskScheduler-24] DEBUG conference.logger

where as I need it to use the class name its coming from like all the rest of our logs do

> 2017-03-30 18:30:11.576 [taskScheduler-24] DEBUG com.foo.bar

We can see the appender is there (in the rootLogger)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

FYI: renamed logger to conferenceLogger

```
private void conferenceLogger(Long meetingId, String className, Log log, Level level, String message, Throwable error) {
    addConferenceLogAppender(className);
    ThreadContext.put(LOG_FILE_NAME, String.valueOf(meetingId));
    logger(log, level, message, error);
    ThreadContext.remove(LOG_FILE_NAME);
    removeConferenceLogAppender(className);

}

static void removeConferenceLogAppender(String package_name) {
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
    Appender appender = configuration.getAppender("ConferenceLog");
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = configuration.getLoggerConfig(package_name);
    loggerConfig.removeAppender(appender.getName());
    context.updateLoggers();
}

static void addConferenceLogAppender(String package_name) {
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
    Appender appender = configuration.getAppender("ConferenceLog");
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = configuration.getLoggerConfig(package_name);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, loggerConfig.getLevel(), null);
    context.updateLoggers();
}
```